# Embed/inject $request array into Drupal 7 function

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a $request array in my custom module that references/makes calls to an API library in my /libraries directory. Currently in my module this $request sits outside of my module hook_node_view function. It works this way. However I would like to inject/embed the $request array into hook_node_view function so it processes from within the Drupal function. When I do this however it stops working and does not make the correct calls to the library.

Thoughts on how best to build out the Drupal function so it can handle this array?

Here's an example of the $request:

```
<?php
$request = array(
    'template_id' => 'Template ID',
    'activity_id' => 'Activity ID',
    'name' => 'Demo Activity',
    'session_id' => generate(),
    'user_id' => 'User ID',
    'assess_inline' => true,
  );
?>

function assignment_node_view($node, $view_mode)
{

 if ($node->nid == 3356) {
    if ($view_mode == 'full') {
        $node->content['my_extra_content'] = array(
            "#markup" => '<div id="assess"></div>',
            "#weight" => 100,
        );

    }
  }
  if ($node->nid == 3354) {
    if ($view_mode == 'full') {
        $node->content['my_extra_content'] = array(
            "#markup" => '<div id="assess"></div>',
            "#weight" => 100,

        );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...it seems that Drupal has it's own `$request` global array and when you re-define it out of function you actually are changing that Drupal's array with your data.

But when you do that from the function you are making just a local `$request` array, available only in that function and global Drupal's array stays unchanged.

Try adding:

```
global $request;
```

in your function before you start using that array.

However, I don't think that it's proper way to achieve what every you are trying to.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid global. Instead create a function like mymodule_get_request() than return the request. You can then call this function inside your hooks.

You can even add static cache to minimize the cost of the function call if you have heavy calculation.